# Freeing a Dynamically Allocated Array of Structs After Function Return.

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc

I have a function that parses a file, and puts it's data into a dynamically allocated array of  structs.  The function returns this dynamically allocated array of the user defined data type.
I want to free this array that was used in the parsing function, how do I do this?  Here is the code I use to allocate the array.

`DownloadDescription_t* pDownloads = (DownloadDescription_t*) malloc(MDLFDescription ->    uiNumberOfLocations *sizeof(DownloadDescription_t));`

And the DownloadDescription_t struct is defined like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
  UINT uiIndex;
  UINT uiDateAdded;
  char caFileName[129];
  char caUserName[50];
  char caSubsystem[10];
} DownloadDescription_t;
```

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: As an aside, if this is C++ code you really want to use `new`, not `malloc`, unless you are sharing the array with pure C code.

Comment: Can extern "C" be a moment for a malloc in c++ ?

Comment: No. `extern "C"` is about linkage. It doesn't turn your code into C code.

Comment: Better yet use a vector and let it free itself.

Comment: This code is shared with C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Let's guess, you have a function contain the code you post, like

`DownloadDescription_t * yourFunctionName( ... )`

Then you call it in main ,  since you return the pointer to main , you need a value to store it , just like:

`DownloadDescription_t * newName = yourFunctionName( ... );`

Then you use the pointer and the data do all you need.

After all that, now you sure the memory need clear just use :`free (newname);`

OK now you can do other thing and end you `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
free(pDownloads);
```

to free the array object.

For every `malloc` call, you should have exactly one `free` call.

Comment: Note, however, that if the individual `structs` in the array have pointers (which is not the case here, but is something to beware of in other cases), you should walk the array first and `free()` whatever those pointers point to (and if those objects contain pointers... you get the picture).

Comment: I cannot free before the return or I will lose the data right?  The pDownloads element is returned to main from this function.  My apologies if I didn't make that clear.  Or do you recommend 'code' free(pDownloads); return pDownloads; '/code'

Comment: @DakotaDiehl You should `free` your array when you are sure you no longer need to use it.